# Copy Formula to a range

Tags: vba

Would like to copy a formula from a cell to a range by using variables. It works fine with xlPasteFormulas but want to avoid it. This formula used wrong references so endresult is wrong:

```
With ActiveSheet
    .Range(.Cells(rowStarWs1, colAct), .Cells(rowLast, colAct)).Formula = .Cells(rowSuch2Ws1, colAct).Formula 
End With
```

Example:
Formula is saved in cell C3 (e.g. A3*B3)

Would like to paste the formula to range C10:C13. Range is given by my variables.

Result should look like below (Yellow cells)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find using `R1C1` notation very helpful when moving formulas around, especially in simple cases like the one you illustrated. More consideration is needed for more complex cases.

```
Sub f()

    Dim f As String
    f = Range("C3").FormulaR1C1
    
    Range("C10:C13").FormulaR1C1 = f
    
End Sub
```

or

```
Range("C10:C13").FormulaR1C1 = Range("C3").FormulaR1C1
```

Comment: Thanks but as I said would like to use the variables instead of hardcoded: "C10:C13"

Comment: I placed the hardcoded ranges in for demo only. You can easily replace with the variables

Comment: Ok, I really don't get that. If worked fine with a simple formula like in my example A3*B3 or A3&B3 but not for a Formula like this below. It referes to other ranges: WENNFEHLER(WENN(C2<>"";WENN(ODER(LINKS(C2)=Tab!$H$5:$H$37);C2;WENNFEHLER(GLÄTTEN(RECHTS(C2;LÄNGE(C2)-MIN(SUCHEN({"@";",";";";":";"/()"))));RECHTS(C2;LÄNGE(C2)-SUCHEN(" ";C2))));"");"")

Comment: @Eli3 - you are going to have to adjust those ranges to match the `R1C1` notation. It will be tricky, because there are a lot of references, but it can be worked out. I have done in the past. Considering two people have answered your question as originally posted, perhaps you can consider marking one as answered, since you have stated both work for your question as posted.

Comment: Thought can bypass using any R1C1 references because the formula is in a cell.

Answer (score 0):

You might use `FillDown` for this purpose.

```
Cells(10, 3).Formula = Cells(3, 3).FormulaR1C1
Range("C10:C14").FillDown
```

`FillDown` copies the formula from the first cell of the defined range to all its cells. Therefore the first line of code fills that first cell. Assigning the R1C1 format to the `Formula` property changes the cells referenced in the formula without using the R1C1 format in the output.

Comment: does not work. Do have a range to paste: Range(cells(Cells(7,4), cells(100,4))

Comment: That's right: Range(cells(Cells(7,4), cells(100,4)) is wrong syntax. Try `Range(Cells(7,4), Cells(100,4)).FillDown` after `Cells(7,4).Formula = Cells(3, 3).FormulaR1C1` presuming that the original formula is in Cells(3,3) (=C3)

Comment: It worked, but same problem as described above. worked for simple formulas but not for others. Unfortunatelly I still have to use .Copy / Paste:=xlPasteFormulas which is slow, but worked fine.